# Installing python with path variables via batch script

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, path

I'm trying to install python and 1 pypi module programmatically via a batch script, to allow me to run a script I wrote that needs that module, on several PCs. A batch script will make it easier to install. I have tried

```
    \\server\share\python-3.6.1.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 Include_pip=1 Include_test=0 PrependPath=1
    python -m pip install utm
    pause
```

Without success. When run, this throws the error `‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I realize this means the system path variables have not been updated correctly, but I thought `PrependPath=1` was setting these variables correctly. Any help anyone could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to close `cmd` and open a new instance of `cmd` to get the new PATH value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrependPath` will add to the path, you have to re-read the path again in order for the command to work.

You can re-read the path by using [`RefreshEnv.cmd` from chocolatey](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/master/src/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd), or simply customize the path for the installation, and then pass the full path to the Python executable, like this:

```
\\server\share\python-3.6.1.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 TargetDir=%ProgramFiles%\Python3.6 Include_pip=1 Include_test=0 PrependPath=1
%ProgramFiles%\Python3.6\python.exe -m pip install utm
```

Comment: This almost worked. However, it installed python in `C:\program\ ` and gave me the error message `C:\program is not a recognized command`.

Comment: Ah of course, Windows. You can try running the command via PowerShell, or simply use a non-spaced path, like `TargetDir=C:\Python\Python3.6`

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. I'll test this later tonight then mark it as solved.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Or just add the required quotes, e.g. `set "TARGETDIR=%ProgramFiles%\Python3.6"` and install to `TargetDir="%TARGETDIR%"` and run `"%TARGETDIR%\python.exe" -m pip install utm`.